# Showing a liste of alias recorded in AndroidKeyStore

Tags: java, android

I try this code to show the list of alias recorded in `AndroidKeyStore` .But nothing is displayed in the `ListView`. Somebody has an idea about what's wrong in the code !

```
ArrayList<String> alia= new ArrayList<String>();
try{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    ks.load(null);
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();   
    while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
      String alias= aliases.toString();
        alias = (String)aliases.nextElement();
        alia.add(alias);     
    }
}
catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,alia);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: do you get any execption?

Comment: Well the first line of code in your while loop is unnecessary but harmless. Are you sure that you actually put some keys into the AndroidKeyStore?

Comment: You can only get access to the key that your app(uid) actually put in the keystore